# WCF Services - Best Practices for grouping Classes

Tags: c#, wcf, architecture

We're planning our architecture and considering how to group our Classes into WCF Services.

We could create one Service per Class or tight collection of Classes. For instance, one Service for everything to do with User Data. That would lead to quite a lot of relatively small Services.

Alternatively, we could create groupings of Classes into a Service. For instance, one service to include Classes for all data entities (User, Order, Customer etc etc).

Or something in between.

I may have a misconception about how these should be related or be looking in the wrong places, but I can't find any guidance.

Is having many Services a bad idea? Do they each have a significant overhead? If we did group them and later wanted to change the groupings, would that be an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would determine which portions of my logic need to be available for consumers of the Services.

Will it be a set of CRUD-like services, lots of adds, updates, deletes?  WebAPI may be a good lightweight alternative to WCF.  Added benefit is that you'd make the services accessible to a wider array of consumers (not just .NET) out of the box, if you see that use case as something that's valuable.

I'd look at how you see your consumers using your service.  I don't see any additional overhead costs to having one monolithic vs many smaller services.  It may even be advantageous from an app pool standpoint to have multiple smaller services.

I don't think there's a wrong way to organize the services, honestly.  The fact that you're thinking about it is reason enough for me to believe you won't mess it up.

Comment: Thanks but I's still not clear. We will have a set of data entities, each of which will need CRUD. We expect we'll create a base class for these to handle the common elements and I'm thinking the base and all its children would go in one Service and that we'd need to handle scaling (as it would get used a lot) by running that service in multiple instances using the appropriate Instance Context Mode. We would then have other services for collections of similar sets of business functionality etc.

Comment: Are these Windows Workflow services?  Look up the Request/Response pattern.  Scaling can be handled by IIS, then multiple servers w/ a Load Balancer.  You want to make your service calls as atomic as possible, so you don't need to maintain session or a connection to the same server. RequestDoWork, DoWork, return ResponseDoWork.

Comment: The service presentation lay will be Web UI.  I think I understand now.  Only those classes/ services that need to be exposed to the Presentation Layer should be in WCF.  Other classes are just in one ore more Class Libraries.  Is that correct? WCF can just call them without worrying about WCF.

Comment: Correct!  Only need to expose methods via WCF that need to be accessed by code that otherwise wouldn't have access to the methods you have in your own class library.

Comment: Thanks, however, I am still unclear on whether having a separate service for each object (Customer, Order, Invoice etc etc) or one for all or some kind of grouping in between is the right way to go.

Comment: There's not one correct way of doing it.  If you have a car dealership, it may make sense to have Audi, Volvo, and Hyundai, all with their own OilChange() and TireRotation(), but exposed as one adapter service, that has OilChange(CarMakerType) and TireRotation(CarMakerType).  Or you may want to have it separate for other valid reasons.  Just make a choice, write it on the white board, and stick with it unless there are massive, delivery-date-affecting reasons for changing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at providing Data to a client, you might want to look at OData just for pure data transmission, and then have service methods on your OData service for any special processing needs.  That would be my advice.  I've seen some real bad WCF implementations because they used WCF for both data transmission and for processing.  OData has client libraries for a ton of different programming languages. By using OData, and Interceptors you can save a HUGE amount of coding time.

Edit:

I should mention that OData isn't necessarily a panacea, in fact, some use cases would lend more towards a DTO (Data Transfer Object) with AutoMapper (nuget package) implementation, but I am a big fan of OData.

Additional Edit:

I know DTO and AutoMapper is a bit more Verbose in code, but I keep thinking from a Xamarin Mobile perspective, where those DTO classes push right into your Mobile project, and mapping out using your service becomes painless and quick, plus you get a lot of code re-use.  Especially if you need local data-caching on the mobile device in SQLLite.